# Reduce googleapis package size for lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

I am using a serverless app to handle my api call

I am using `google.auth.GoogleAuth` and `google.androidpublisher` from `googleapis` package

There is a limitation in the code size which can be uploaded to lambda and `googleapis` is `115 MB`, this is huge !!!

I found an article telling that calling packages like that `const {androidpublisher_v3} = require('googleapis/build/src/apis/androidpublisher')` will reduce the package size but no.

Running `sls package` I always have 115MB of `googleapis`

Is there any way to reduce that ? I was thinking to code the calls by myself but this is a few hours of work

Comment: Which is bundler in your project? webpack or esbuild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option #1: Use a bundler tool

Take a look at https://github.com/floydspace/serverless-esbuild. Once setup, it will do the tree-shaking to reduce your code size by including only the code your Lambda actually imports.

So if you mention `const {androidpublisher_v3} = require('googleapis/build/src/apis/androidpublisher')` in your code, `esbuild` will include only the parts of the `googleapis` package that you need for the `AndroiPublisher` module.

**Pros:** universal way, automatic;

**Cons:** some packages with native code might break and require exclusion; slower

### Option #2: Delete unneeded file from `node_modules`

When you use [yarn package manager](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) instead of npm, you can provide an [exclusion list](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/autoclean/) of paths you want to clean up automatically from your `node_modules` during installation.

I wrote an in-depth article about this topic: https://itnext.io/3x-smaller-lambda-artifacts-by-removing-junk-from-node-modules-2b50780ca1f5

In essence, you create a `.yarnclean` file in your repository with the following content:

```
**/googleapis/build/src/apis/compute
**/googleapis/build/src/apis/dfareporting
**/googleapis/build/src/apis/displayvideo
**/googleapis/build/src/apis/healthcare
**/googleapis/build/src/apis/dialogflow
**/googleapis/build/src/apis/retail
**/googleapis/build/src/apis/securitycenter
# ... more rules to follow
```

Continue the list of folders that you don't need in your Lambda.

Specifically for `googleapis` package, ~70% of the artifact size could be removed, by removing typings from the package.

You need TypeScript types only during development, but not in Lambda runtime.

So you can add this code to your CI pipeline before making an artifact.

I was able to reduce the size of the code from 111 MB to 20 MB just by executing the following snippet alone:

```bash
npx del-cli \
  "node_modules/**/@types/**" \
  "node_modules/**/*.d.ts" \
  "node_modules/**/.yarn-integrity" \
  "node_modules/**/.bin"
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sharing my point may be helpful in future for someone.
I was working with serverless node.js and serverless has limit of 250mb when deploying code. [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) was 286mb so when I run "serverless deploy" it throws error [image: unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes]. For decreasing size of googleapis I just used these commands

1. Install `npm install --global del-cli`
2. `npx del-cli "node_modules/**/@types/**"`
3. `npx del-cli "node_modules/**/*.d.ts"`
4. `npx del-cli "node_modules/**/.yarn-integrity"`
5. `npx del-cli "node_modules/**/.bin"`

Before running these commands my lambda function size was **286mb** and after it has been reduced **140mb**.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the size by importing tree shaken submodules now.

`yarn add @googleapis/androidpublisher`

Then import like so `const androidPublisher = require('@googleapis/androidpublisher');`

Here is a list of the others https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node#google-cloud-nodejs-client-libraries